# Cannot visit http://127.0.0.1:4839 because the browseURL function is disabled

Tags: r, shinyapps

I am using R studio
My R Script works on windows local but when I deploy to shinyapp.io I got error

Running on host: 2b3907634cee

```
2021-12-17T18:47:55.066298+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: Server version: 2021.11.0
2021-12-17T18:47:55.066314+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: LANG: C.UTF-8
2021-12-17T18:47:55.066315+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: R version: 4.1.2
2021-12-17T18:47:55.066316+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: shiny version: 1.7.1
2021-12-17T18:47:55.066316+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: httpuv version: 1.6.3
2021-12-17T18:47:55.066326+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: rmarkdown version: (none)
2021-12-17T18:47:55.066337+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: jsonlite version: 1.7.2
2021-12-17T18:47:55.066332+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: knitr version: (none)
2021-12-17T18:47:55.066376+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: RJSONIO version: (none)
2021-12-17T18:47:55.066395+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: htmltools version: 0.5.2
2021-12-17T18:47:55.066601+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.11
2021-12-17T18:47:55.312822+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2021-12-17T18:47:55.316416+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: 
2021-12-17T18:47:55.316417+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: Starting R with process ID: '25'
2021-12-17T18:47:55.316842+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: Shiny application starting ...
2021-12-17T18:47:55.340051+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: Loading required package: mirt
2021-12-17T18:47:55.344193+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: Loading required package: stats4
2021-12-17T18:47:55.386349+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: Loading required package: lattice
2021-12-17T18:47:56.886259+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: Loading required package: DBI
2021-12-17T18:48:03.223772+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: 
2021-12-17T18:48:03.223774+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4839
2021-12-17T18:48:03.224735+00:00 shinyapps[5309142]: Cannot visit http://127.0.0.1:4839 because the browseURL function is disabled.
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a `browseURL` function in your script?

Comment: @Dubukay No browseURL function in my script.